# Is there a way to compress exe files?

Tags: windows, compression

Compressing EXE files either using WinRAR or 7Zip does not yield anything, meaning, the compressed RAR or 7Zip file is just the same size of the EXE file, is there a way to compress EXE file and get at least about 15-20 compression ratio?

Answer (score 6):

Normally, x86 machine code does compress quite well (not by a factor of 15-20 though). So if the exe does not compress well, this indicates that it might already be compressed. There are some tools to self-decompress exe files when run, so the user wouldn't even notice that it is compressed. For example, Wikipedia contains a list of programs that are able to [compress the Windows "Portable Executable" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression#Portable_Executable). Compressing an exe file that is already compressed by any of those tools will not result in any real benefit.

Alternatively, the exe might contain large assets, like JPEG graphics or compressed audio, which can not be compressed well.

I guess without more information on the exe file and what you want to achieve, you are out of luck.

Comment: "There are some tools to self-decompress exe files when run, so the user wouldn't even notice that it is compressed" leaves the obvious question: "sounds great, what are some of those tools?" =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Added a link to a list of some tools on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 compact command includes an option for compressing executable file.

/EXE       Use compression optimized for executable files which are read
frequently and not modified.  Supported algorithms are:

```
         XPRESS4K  (fastest) (default)
         XPRESS8K
         XPRESS16K
         LZX       (most compact)

Compact /c /exe:lzx <name>
```

Comment: `The compression ratio is 1.0 to 1.` as per output when I tried it.

Comment: @cyberquarks There must be something unusual about your file. I chose an EXE at random and got 8.8. to 1.

Comment: Note that the compact command does not compress "files", it compresses regions of your volume/disk. The given command doesn't modify the file to achieve compression, it performs compression below the filesystem level, so your file will still report as having its original size even if "on disk" it's now taking up fewer bytes, and copying it to a new location will create a copy of the original file, not the compressed byte sequence.

Answer (score -1):

If you are unable to compress the `.exe` with 7Zip, it is likely already compressed with an executable compressor like [UPX](https://upx.github.io/).

You can detect if this is the case with the PEiD tool.

Comment: There is already an answer that says this, but with more and better information. When answering old questions that already have answers, it is best not to post duplicates of existing information unless you have something substantial to add.

Comment: @music2myear where do you see another answer that mentions UPX already? I don't.